# Range string to individual split

Tags: r, split, range

I have a data frame col contains a range of cost centre value strings.

```
A6652 - A6670
```

I want to achieve in the next col to split them up as

[image: Output wanted]

How can I do it in R?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution is this:

```r
# your data
df <- data.frame(costcentre.range = rep("A6652 - A6670", 19))

# solution
library(stringr) # required for `str_extract()`

df$individual <- paste0(
    "A", as.integer(str_extract(df$costcentre.range, "\\d+")) + 0:(nrow(df)-1))
```

A more complex solution, say, if the `costcentre.range` doesn't always start with "A" or you have a second set of ranges, can look like this:

```r
# data with "A66##" and "B77##" individuals
df2 <- data.frame(
    costcentre.range = c(rep("A6651 - A6660", 10), rep("B7781 - B7790", 10)))

# solution
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)

df2 <- df2 %>% 
    mutate(first_id = str_extract(costcentre.range, "[A-Z]\\d+")) %>% 
    separate(first_id, c("letter", "number"), "(?<=[A-Z])(?=\\d+)", convert = TRUE) %>%
    group_by(costcentre.range) %>% 
    mutate(number = number + 0:(n()-1)) %>% 
    unite(individual, letter, number, sep = "")
```

```r
df2

## A tibble: 20 x 2
## Groups:   costcentre.range [2]
#   costcentre.range individual
#   <fct>            <chr>     
# 1 A6651 - A6660    A6651     
# 2 A6651 - A6660    A6652     
# 3 A6651 - A6660    A6653     
# 4 A6651 - A6660    A6654     
# 5 A6651 - A6660    A6655     
# 6 A6651 - A6660    A6656     
# 7 A6651 - A6660    A6657     
# 8 A6651 - A6660    A6658     
# 9 A6651 - A6660    A6659     
#10 A6651 - A6660    A6660     
#11 B7781 - B7790    B7781     
#12 B7781 - B7790    B7782     
#13 B7781 - B7790    B7783     
#14 B7781 - B7790    B7784     
#15 B7781 - B7790    B7785     
#16 B7781 - B7790    B7786     
#17 B7781 - B7790    B7787     
#18 B7781 - B7790    B7788     
#19 B7781 - B7790    B7789     
#20 B7781 - B7790    B7790
```

The first goal is to extract the first ID string in the range values (`str_extract()`). 
Then separate the letter values from the number values so that you can treat the number values as integers (`separate()`), 
which you can then use addition to change the numbers (`mutate(number = ...)`). 
Note that `group_by(costcentre.range)` and `n()` together give you the group sizes of the unique values in `costcentre.range`. 
Finally, unite the letters and the new numbers back together again, forming the new column (`unite()`).

Answer (score 0):

Using data from @LC-datascientist post here is a `tidyverse` way to do this.

Keep only unique rows in the data, split the `costcentre.range` into two columns (`start` and `end`), create a sequence between them and unnest the data in long format.

```
library(tidyverse)

df2 <- data.frame(
  costcentre.range = c(rep("A6651 - A6660", 10), rep("B7781 - B7790", 10)))

df2 %>%
  distinct() %>%
  separate(costcentre.range, c('start', 'end'), sep = '\\s-\\s') %>%
  mutate(group = sub('([A-Z]+).*', '\\1', start),
         across(c(start, end), .fns = parse_number), 
         individual = map2(start, end, seq)) %>%
  unnest(individual) %>%
  unite(individual, group, individual, sep = '') %>%
  select(individual)
```

This returns -

```
# individual
#   <chr>     
# 1 A6651     
# 2 A6652     
# 3 A6653     
# 4 A6654     
# 5 A6655     
# 6 A6656     
# 7 A6657     
# 8 A6658     
# 9 A6659     
#10 A6660     
#11 B7781     
#12 B7782     
#13 B7783     
#14 B7784     
#15 B7785     
#16 B7786     
#17 B7787     
#18 B7788     
#19 B7789     
#20 B7790
```

Comment: Why only one can be ticked?  Sad.  Yours excellent too.  Actually, we have many ways to achieve our goals in this.